# Connector for connecting two diagram in flex4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6

I have drawn a connector connecting two diagram but i am not able to select connector so that i can perform operations like copy paste resize.But i am able to select diagrams.Please guide me......

Comment: Would you show us your drawing? Please be more specific to let understand your issue.

Comment: sir i have less reputation so i am not able to show drawing...But I am explaning here: i drag and drop two or three diagram from a container named Diagram palette.After that i click on a button(used for connector)then draw connector connecting above draged diagram.how should i perform copy paste of all diagram and connector.